# Can HDFS data node be abstract?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloud

Is there any posibility to use abstract data node in HDFS?
If I (for example) want to run Hadoop but not on hardware but on some kind of software, cloud, etc., is there any API which allows that?
Is there an alternative to Hadoop which offers that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes... There's an [embedded hadoop minicluster](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/CLIMiniCluster.html)  that is contained within a single JVM

Any Hadoop you do run in the cloud or a VM is still on hardware at some layer, though.

However the purpose of HDFS is a **distributed** filesystem, so if you want use something else to store your data, and you don't want to use Hadoop, then just use that instead (Ceph, Openstack Swift, Minio, NFS)

Comment: I guess my question was kinda not correct. Is it possible to have abstract DataNode? If I had a cloud and API to use it, would there be any interface to implement so I could make them work together?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "a cloud". There are several Hadoop compatible filesystems https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HCFS Hadoop already supports Amazon S3, Google  GCS, and Azure WASB